# Do you "create" a hypothesis?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, formality

What is the most appropriate verb when talking about making a new hypothesis? E.g.

> Lenneburg created the critical period hypothesis.
>
> Lenneburg coined the critical period hypothesis.
>
> Lenneburg came up with the critical period hypothesis.
>
> Lenneburg termed the critical period hypothesis.

...etc. I don't know which sounds the most appropriate.

Comment: 'coined' is not right. 'termed' is for -naming- the thing not initiating it. 'create' or 'came up' with both work (the latter more informal)

Comment: The ... hypothesis was first put forward by L.

Comment: Okay, well what these answers are telling me is that there are several equally valid and varyingly popular constructions, which is reassuring. I don't know which answer to accept though, because they all give useful information.

Answer (score 10):

**[Formulate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/formulate?q=formulate)** can be used in this context.

Express (an idea) in a concise or systematic way:
the argument is sufficiently clear that it can be formulated mathematically

[Formulating hypotesis](http://www.slideshare.net/aniket0013/formulating-hypotheses) I add this link just for referene.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulate%20an%20hypothesis,advance%20an%20hypothesis,put%20forward%20an%20hypothesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,formulate%20an%20hypothesis;,c0;.t1;,advance%20an%20hypothesis;,c0;.t1;,put%20forward%20an%20hypothesis;,c0)

Comment: Try using "a" instead of "an" in your Ngram.

Comment: Still 'formulate' is the most common.

Answer (score 8):

One suitable word is ***postulate***

> **hypothesis**
>   A supposition or proposed explanation made on the basis of limited evidence as a starting point for further investigation [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypothesis)
>
> **postulate**
>   Suggest or assume the existence, fact, or truth of (something) as a basis for reasoning, discussion, or belief [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/postulate)

*Postulate* is to suggest a fact as a basis for reasoning or discussion; a *hypothesis* is a suggestion made as a starting point for further examination. The terms converge.

Comment: There's not much scope for using the verb 'postulate' anywhere else. It takes a 'synonymous object'.

Comment: Is that a bad thing, Edwin?

Comment: @Leo King It's an interesting thing. I've spent quite some time looking at semantic restrictions on direct objects, and the differentiation of things-looking-like-DO's from true DO's (The piano had a stool / they had a ball / he died a hero / he looked daggers at her / he danced attendance on her / they weighed anchor ...). I can't remember coming across a verb with a 'synonymous' DO.

Answer (score 5):

Some alternatives culled from Google:

developed, proposed, formulated, advanced, put forward, introduced

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulated+the+hypothesis%2Cadvanced+the+hypothesis%2Cdeveloped+the+hypothesis%2Cput+forward+the+hypothesis%2Cproposed+the+hypothesis%2Cintroduced+the+hypothesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformulated%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvanced%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeveloped%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20forward%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproposed%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintroduced%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0) suggests "advanced" has been the most common of these until the last 30 years when "put forward" overtook it.

Comment: Yes, but bear in mind *put forward* includes both present and past tense contexts. If you [add together ***advance*** and ***advanced***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+forward+the+hypothesis%2C(advanced+the+hypothesis)+%2B+(advance+the+hypothesis)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20forward%20the%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28advanced%20the%20hypothesis%29%20%2B%20%28advance%20the%20hypothesis%29%3B%2Cc0) that verb is still the front-runner.

Comment: As for NGram, it depends on what inputs you use. I used 'formulate, advance, put forward an hypothesis' .. And the results are different!!!

Comment: @Josh61: My point exactly. But I've no doubt *past* tense would be more common overall for every different verb. It's just a skew factor that things like ***put** forward* and ***set** out* cover both tenses at once.

Comment: Yes, point taken.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have mentioned, you can **[hypothesize](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22we%20hypothesize%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5)** a hypothesis.

> put (something) forward as a hypothesis.

Here's a sample [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28formulate%20the%20hypothesis%29%2b%28formulated%20the%20hypothesis%29,%28advanced%20the%20hypothesis%29%2b%28advance%20the%20hypothesis%29,%28we%20hypothesized%29%2b%28we%20hypothesize%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28formulate%20the%20hypothesis%29%20%2b%20%28formulated%20the%20hypothesis%29;,c0;.t1;,%28advanced%20the%20hypothesis%29%20%2b%20%28advance%20the%20hypothesis%29;,c0;.t1;,%28we%20hypothesized%29%20%2b%20%28we%20hypothesize%29;,c0) comparing with other answers. Note that Google Ngram does not cull from scholarly articles, so it might not capture academic norms and preferences, which likely vary by discipline, too.

[image]

Comment: Not as catchy as 'I have dreamed a dream'. Cognate objects aren't often used without modification (He slept the sleep of the righteous). And you weren't fair in not choosing 'we hypothesize/d a/the hypothesis' (which predictably flatline) for comparison.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't "we hypothesized" usually followed by the actual hypothesis?

Comment: In answers, we're supposed to address OP's question, which here is 'Do you 'create' a hypothesis? ... Lenneburg ____ the critical period hypothesis. (x 4) ... I don't know which sounds the most appropriate.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Apart from the OPs example, in which case "hypothesize" would not be a suitable verb because of repetition, "hypothesize" still addresses the OPs question, "What is the most appropriate verb when talking about making a new hypothesis?" Instead of "We formulated hypothesis X," I am suggesting "We hypothesized X" as a more succinct alternative. This changes the meaning slightly, but I don't think it falls out of the OPs range. Moreover, "hypothesize" is regularly used in [scholarly articles](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22we%20hypothesize%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

Answer (score 2):

Consider "[**form**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/form)."

> Lenneberg [**formed**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=form+a+hypothesis%2Cformulate+a+hypothesis%2Cput+forward+a+hypothesis%2Cadvance+a+hypothesis&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cform%20a%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulate%20a%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20forward%20a%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadvance%20a%20hypothesis%3B%2Cc0) [**the critical period hypothesis**](http://www.writework.com/essay/question-language-acquisition-lenneberg-vs-chomsky).
>
> A "[**lipid hypothesis was formed**](http://ezinearticles.com/?Absolute-Most-Fattening-Foods-and-Ingredients&id=6150172)" to explain the rapid increase of heart disease.

Answer (score 0):

Alongside 'propose', 'put forward', and possibly 'postulate' and 'formulate' (though I'm not a fan of either of these), you can simply use 'hypothesise'/'hypothesize' as a verb in its own right.